# Getting MSBuild to compile project with dependencies for Win32 and Win64 platforms

Tags: c++, msbuild, visual-studio-2013, msbuild-task

I have a large solution with over 10 projects in it, in C++.

The entire solution  is *x64* only, except for project **P** which needs both both *x64* and *win32* versions ( the proper one is loaded at runtime).

Project **P** depends on several other projects for lib files: **C** and **H** which are compiled into libs.

**P** has a reference to **C** and **H** like so:

```
<ProjectReference Include="..\C\C.vcxproj">
   <Project>{....}</Project>
</ProjectReference>
<ProjectReference Include="..\H\H.vcxproj">
   <Project>{....}</Project>
</ProjectReference>
```

I want to build project **P** for both platforms.

I chose to do this from a **meta-P** project, which calls on **P** like so:

```
<MSBuild Projects="..\P\P.vcxproj" Properties="Platform=Win32"/>
<MSBuild Projects="..\P\P.vcxproj" Properties="Platform=x64"/>
```

This allows **P** to be changed freely by the developers, and then both versions are built at once by building **meta-P**.

The problem is that when **meta-P** calls MSBuild on project **P** the references to **C** and **H** are affected by the Solution environment (in which the active platform is always x64).

When it comes to linking the Win32 **P** to its proper **C.lib** and **H.lib**, the open solution configuration kicks in, and studio attempts to link it with the x64 version, and fails.

I temporarily solved it using an **exec** task in **meta-P** to run *MsBuild.exe* directly on **P**. This ignored the Visual Studio environment properties.

What is the correct solution to have the platform correctly read?

Comment: `.. until Msbuild wants to link the 32bit version of P...` If C and H build code (i.e. they are not include only projects) then to get P to link in the 32 bit instance, C and H will have to be built as 32 bit as well. Do they have Win32 platform targets?

Comment: You'd have to have us do the unfun part, a build diagnostic trace is required to narrow it down.  Shooting off the hip, avoid relying on MSBuild figuring out the project dependencies and specify them explicitly.

Comment: @Niall - yes they have Win32 platform targets, but their default (in the .sln) is x64

Comment: Possibly look to explicitly build all the Win32 targets first (with the platforms specified as such) and then build the 64 bit targets.

Comment: When you build your solution (.sln) file, what is your command line? Are you specifying Platform property on the command line? If so, this will override the Platfrom definitions in all projects.

Comment: This also happens when I rightclick and build project from VS2013.

My eventual solution was to replace MSBuild tasks with Exec task, calling a new MSBuild.exe instance. A shame that **RemoveProperties** option doesn't hold

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct solution is to add an undocumented property called ***ShouldUnsetParentConfigurationAndPlatform*** and set it to **false**.

The only correct place to put it, is within each **Project Reference** item in the **P** project, otherwise it gets ignored.

So it ends up looking like this:

```
<ProjectReference Include="..\C\C.vcxproj">
  <Project>{....}</Project>
  <Properties>ShouldUnsetParentConfigurationAndPlatform=false</Properties>
</ProjectReference>
<ProjectReference Include="..\H\H.vcxproj">
  <Project>{....}</Project>
  <Properties>ShouldUnsetParentConfigurationAndPlatform=false</Properties>
</ProjectReference>
```

This causes Visual Studio to follow through with **C**'s and **H**'s inherited properties, instead of reading them from the Solution environment.

Edit: see useful reference from comment:
https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/blob/98d38cb/src/XMakeTasks/AssignProjectConfiguration.cs#L198-L218

Comment: For reference: https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/blob/98d38cb/src/XMakeTasks/AssignProjectConfiguration.cs#L198-L218.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you need Meta-P. At work we had a similar issue.

In P, we added an ItemGroup with the two vcxproj :

```
<CppProjects Include="...\P64.vcxproj">
  <Properties>Platform=x64</Properties>
</CppProjects>
<CppProjects Include="...\P32.vcxproj">
  <Properties>Platform=Win32</Properties>
</CppProjects>
```

The Platform meta-data will force the expected platform.

Then add a build dependency in P.csproj with :

```
<Target Name="BuildCpp" BeforeTargets="Build">
  <MSBuild Projects="@(CppProjects)" Properties="Configuration=$(Configuration)" RemoveProperties="Platform" />
</Target>
```

Comment: The problem is I don't want the rest of the team supporting 2 separate projects for the same content. Sometimes P is even changed by a different team, responsible for various aspects of P.

I eventually ran MSBuild.exe twice with Exec task, because any other way, scoping issues would lead MSbuild to link 32bits with 64bits and fail.